# How to create directories containing index.html with wget --recursive?

Tags: wget, recursive

I'm pretty happy how `wget -r` works and downloads the things.

I have set up a localhost server which serves a website and the pages look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8080/foo
http://localhost:8080/bar
http://localhost:8080/blog/
http://localhost:8080/blog/1-and-here-the-slug
```

When I use `wget -r localhost:8080` it creates the following structure:

```
.
├── static-files
│   └── ...
├── bar
├── blog
│   └── 1-and-here-the-slug
├── foo
└── index.html
```

`bar`, `foo`  and `1-and-here-the-slug` are files. I want them to be directories with a single file in them, named `index.html` and still not breaking the paths to the resources (CSS, JS etc).

I expect something like this:

```
.
├── static-files
│   └── ...
├── bar
│   └── index.html
├── foo
│   └── index.html
├── blog
│   ├── index.html // <---------- Also I want this one here to show the blog
│   └── 1-and-here-the-slug
│       └── index.html
└── index.html
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does `--trust-server-names` help?

Comment: @JigglyNaga Not really. I don't see any change. The filenames are there like before, without any extension, but I want them to be directories containing `index.html`.

Comment: Please could you include `-S` in the `wget` options and show the output?  The directory requests (where you would expect `index.html`) may involve redirections, so it's necessary to see the exact response(s).

Comment: *The directory requests ...*––they are *not* directories. They are simple pathnames in the browser but resolved by the local server. For example `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions` will be downloaded as a file `questions` but what I want is to have `questions/index.html`.

Comment: So you want to ignore the original layout, and create a bunch of extra directories where files used to be?  There's no `wget` option to do that -- you'd have to use a script to download-then-rename.  And at that point, it will be too late for the `wget -k` option ( to convert the links, so the resource paths still work) to be any use.  *And* you will need a special case so that `index.html` doesn't become `index.html/index.html`.  What are you trying to achieve with all this?

Comment: @JigglyNaga Yes, correct. For those `index.html` they will simply remain `index.html`. It's because I want to get the same path structure in the browser when serving it as static website. So, that means when accessing in the browsers `example.com/questions` it will resolve to `example.com/questions/index.html` (that's done by most of the static servers), but the link will still remain in the address bar `example.com/questions`.

Comment: @Ionică Bizău , perhaps you may try to do the other way around - force the local HTTP server to treat the files as htmls, smth like `AddType` in `.htaccess`

Comment: @RostislavKandilarov No, for instance I want to publish the result files on GitHub Pages, where I don't have control to such things. They serve a directory if it contains `index.html` inside.

Answer (score 2):

> `http://localhost:8080/blog/1-and-here-the-slug`
>
> bar, foo and 1-and-here-the-slug are files. I want them to be directories with a single file in them, named index.html and still not breaking the paths to the resources (CSS, JS etc).

```
├── blog
│   └── 1-and-here-the-slug
│       └── index.html
```

When you access `http://localhost:8080/blog/1-and-here-the-slug` the current directory is `blog`, if you rename that page to be `blog/1-and-here-the-slug/index.html`, your new current directory would be `blog/1-and-here-the-slug`. So you will break the relative paths inside the resource (CSS, JS), if any. And **there's no way to solve this question without modifying the inner HTML of the files**.

The best thing you can do is to rename files without any extension to have the html extension.

```
├── blog
│   └── 1-and-here-the-slug.html
```

1. **Keeping the same directory, you can use the `rename` command recursively:**

Ex:

```
  find tmp -type f ! -name '*.*' | rename -nv 's/(.*)/$1.html/'
```

2. **You may create new directories, but this would break the relative resources, if any**

Ex:

```
  find tmp -type f ! -name '*.*' | while read file; do
       mv $file $file.tmp;
       mkdir $file;
       mv $file.tmp $file/index.html;
 done
```

You can play by inserting the `<base href="">` tag in the file to specify the good path to thr resources, but this will be a lot of hard expensive work

2. **Or better, use the `-E` wget parameter

**EDIT: reading `wget` man page give you two wonderful options**

> ```
>   -E
>   --adjust-extension
>        If a file of type application/xhtml+xml or text/html is downloaded
>        and the URL does not end with the regexp \.[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]?, this option
>        will cause the suffix .html to be appended to the local filename. 
>
>   -k
>    --convert-links
>        After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to
>        make them suitable for local viewing.  This affects not only the visible
>        hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links to external content, 
>        such as embedded images, links to style sheets, hyperlinks to non-
>        HTML content, etc.
> ```

Comment: *You may create new directories, but this would break the relative resources, if any*––Exactly, `wget` does have a solution to fix the urls. Is it somehow possible to use that one?

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer, it seems that `-k` and `-E` wget parameters may suit your needs

Comment: Yes, in conclusion, which is the final solution I should use? I did read these manual pages but still it's unclear how to use them in parallel with what I want in the end (creating directories with `index.html` files in them)

Comment: I'd be happy to award you the bounty, but what you answered is actually what I was knowing before too––can you improve the answer?

Comment: As said in my answer, it's not possible to solve this question without modifying the inner html. You can use "adjust extension" option to wget, which will not create intermediate directory (which is equal to the 1st solution I gave) or use the 2nd solution (using `find`) which may break relative resources, but you should give it a try  (as `-k` option may help for non relative ones).

Comment: After encountering a very similar problem to the original poster (although perhaps not 100% identical), I wrote a script that generates index.html files in directories. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74200451/2492933